# How can I prove that (p→q)∧(p→r) ⇔ p→(q∧r)

Tags: logic

How can I prove that (p→q)∧(p→r) compound statements and
compound statement p→(q∧r) are logically equivalent?

And can I use logical equivalences on this proof?

Comment: Via a table of logic?

Answer (score 4):

$$(p\implies q) \land (p\implies r)$$

is equivalent to

$$( q \lor \lnot p) \land ( r \lor \lnot p)$$

is equivalent to

$$(q \land r) \lor \lnot p$$

is equivalent to

$$p \implies (q\land r)$$

Comment: @Elementary:  you can learn MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

$(p→q)∧(p→r) $ is the same as

$(\overline{p} \vee q)\wedge   (\overline{p} \vee r)$ which is the same as

$(\overline{p}\vee(\overline{p}\wedge r)\vee(q\wedge\overline{p})\vee(q\wedge r))$

From here, it is clear that if both $\overline{p}$ and  $(q\wedge r)$ is false, the complete statement is false. If either is true, then the full statement is true.  And so the full statement is the same as the statement $p→(q∧r)$ because  $p→(q∧r)$ is the same as $\overline{p} \vee (q\wedge r)$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers showed how to use logical equivalences to prove the result. Here is a proof using natural deduction in a Fitch-style proof checker.

[image]

The inference rules are listed on the [proof checker's page](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

They are

- [conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) ($\land$I),
- [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) ($\land$E),
- [implication introduction or conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) ($\to$I),
- [implication elimination or modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) ($\to$E) and
- [biconditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction) ($\leftrightarrow$I).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/